# Что лучше использовать для текстового лога? JTextPane или JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

Делаю текстовую игру. Выводить состояние игры лучше в JTextPane или JTextArea? 
Лог игры должен идти так, чтобы новые сообщения появлялись внизу (напоминает чат). Так же хочется, чтобы старые сообщения не стирались, а просто уходили вверх за границу и всегда можно было прокрутить до нужного и прочитать. Пожалуйста, поделитесь кодом, как это сделать, ибо не представляю совершенно.

Интерфейс должен выглядеть так:
[image: Желаемый вид]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую `JTextArea` и `JScrollPane`
и делаю приблизительно так:

поля

```
private JTextArea          text;
private JScrollPane        scroll;
```

при создании формы инициализирую их

```
text = new JTextArea(15, 50);
text.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, text.getFont().getSize()));
text.setEditable(false);

scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

и

```
public void updateText(final String value) {
    if (text != null) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date = new Date();

        text.append(dateFormat.format(date) + " " + value + "\n");

        JScrollBar vertical = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
        vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
    }
}
```

Comment: не работает 'updateText(final String value)'

Comment: Вот прям вы вызвали и просто "молча" ничего не произошло? "Не работает" - плохое описание проблемы

Comment: Повесил на 4 разных кнопки, с разными строками. При отладке в метод проваливается, но JTextArea не обновляется. при нажатии на кнопочки

Comment: Я неашёл в чём у меня был косяк, извиняюсь. Можете ещё подсказать как сделать так, чтобы первые строки появлялись внизу окна, а не сверху как сейчас? Вставить нужное количество пустых строк '\n'? Это нормальное решение или "костыль"?